# SQL Server Management Studio: Unknown error "-1073741766"

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

Why do I get this error when trying to open a table for editing:

```
Unknown error "-1073741766". (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.SQLEditors)
```

Environment:

- SQL Server 2005 Express
- SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005
- Windows Server 2003 (inside VMware)

I am using Remote Desktop to connect to the VM and run Management Studio.

I can use Management Studio on my physical machine to connect to SQL Server in the VM and edit the table in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears to happen only when I do not have access to my roaming profile's "My Documents" folder from within VM. Mounting the network share that is used for "My Documents" at the expected path solves the problem. I can then edit the table from the VM's Management Studio.

I recall having to mount the share for "My Documents" as well during SQL Server installation.